# Snow leopard skinning tools

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, themes

What are the skinning tools available for the Snow Leopard ?

Mostly, I'm interested on skinning the windows, menus and other elements. I only know of ShapeShifter, but it is old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) skins the Dock and changes icons. Window and menu skinning system-wide is not supported in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dock Doctor](http://www.innermindmedia.com/dock_doctor_app.html) to skin my Dock.  It also allows you to toggle between 2D and 3D.